# Explanation of code (linked list C)

Tags: c, linked-list, head

This is not my code. I took this code off this website:

http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~rjp/Coursewww/Cwww/linklist.html

I am using for reference material on how to build a linked list. I'm a little confused on what is going on. Can someone please explain to me what is going on. I'll mark what is confusing me with 1-5.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct list_el {
   int val;
   struct list_el * next;
};

typedef struct list_el item;

void main() {
   item * curr, * head;
   int i;

   head = NULL;   //1

   for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
      curr = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
      curr->val = i;
      curr->next  = head; //2
      head = curr; //3
   }

   curr = head; // 4

   while(curr) {  //5
      printf("%d\n", curr->val);
      curr = curr->next ;
   }
```

1. head = NULL → why is head being set to NULL? I know that you are supposed to (I do it out of habit) but I don't really know why.
2. curr->next = head → I never really understood this as well. Maybe I have my definition of "head" wrong but in a regular linked list, is it the starting node or the last node on the list? I've always assumed it was the starting node but in this line it looks like it's the last node.
3. head = curr → Why are we setting it equal to curr?
4. curr = head → and then setting curr = head after the loop is done.
5. while(curr) → Just to make sure, this is traversing through the list and it is equivalent to while(curr != NULL) right?

Comment: The list is being built by attaching nodes on the front end, and adjusting head to point to the new node.

Comment: This code builds a linked list, so it might help to have a clear understanding of what a linked list is:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> #### #1: `head = NULL`

**Initializing the pointer**. It's *generally* recommended to initialize the pointer to NULL either (1) at declaration or (2) immediately after declaration. If programmers mistakenly dereference uninitialized pointers, garbage values are returned. Often times, this is extremely hard to debug if your static analyzer and compiler don't display warning or error messages for uninitialized pointers.

For more information, please refer to [Steve McConnell's *Code Complete: A Practical Handbook of Software Construction*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) or Wikipedia page on [*Defensive Programming*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming).

> #### #2: `curr->next = head`

**Building the linked list**. The `curr` node is being "linked" to previously created node in the sequence.

> #### #3: `head = curr`

**Updating the head pointer.** The `head` pointer is being updated to point to the most recently `malloc`ed node.

Below illustrations visualize Steps #2 and #3:

[image: first]
[image: second]
[image: third]
[image: forth and final]

> #### #4: `curr = head`

**Re-initializing the pointer.** This step is similar to step #2:`curr->next = head`. By setting `curr` node to `head`, `curr` gets "ready" for linked-list traversal in the `while` loop. Analogically speaking, it's like initializing the iterating variable to 0 in the beginning of the loop (i.e. `i = 0`). To visualize this step, please refer to the below illustrations showing before/after this statement is executed:

[image: before]

[image: after]

> #### #5: `while(curr)`

**Traversing the list.**
Given that `curr` is pointing to the first node (from step #4), this `while` loop traverses the list until `curr->next` returns NULL. In a less abstract form, we can rewrite this statement as `while(curr != NULL)`.

Comment: A truly excellent answer. Very explanatory and easy to understand. Struggling with linked lists atm and this sorted it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

1. head is pointing to the head of the list.  Since the list is currently empty, it's set to null
2. When you add a node to the list, you set the "next" pointer to the current head of the list.  The puts the new node at the head of the list.
3. You set "head" to "curr" to make the new node the head of the list.
4. After the loop is over, you're re-using the "curr" variable to traverse the list.
5. You're going through the list setting "curr" to each node in turn until you go off the bottom of the list (where curr->next is null)

Answer (score 3):

(1). You need to set it to something and using NULL is a way to say it's not pointing to anything.  Usually NULL is the same as 0.  In some languages, you don't need to initialize the variable because it'll automatically set it to nil.  But C doesn't do that so you have to do it yourself.

(2). `head` is pointing to the first node of the list. At first, it is NULL, which means the list is empty and thus `head` not pointing to anything. `cur` is a new node that wants to be inserted into the list. `curr->next` wants to point to the first node of the existing list, so that's why `curr->next` is set to `head`.

(3). At this point `head` is no longer pointing to the first node.  The first time through the loop, it looks like this:

```
curr-->node1-->NULL
         head--^
```

But in general it would look like this

```
curr-->node3-->node2-->node1-->NULL
          head--^
```

So we need to update `head` to point to the first node.  Since `curr` is pointing to the newly created node, which is placed at the front, we just set `head` to point to the same node as `curr`.

(4). The first part of the program is done.  `curr` is no longer needed because it was used to keep track of the new node we created.  It was a temporary variable.  This line `curr = head` means we're going to initialize `curr` to the beginning of the list.  We could've used another variable to make it more readable, but you typically see reuse of temporary variables.

(5). Right. You'll probably see `NULL` defined as `(void*)0`, so it's the same as 0.  You'll probably never see another value other than 0 except for really old machines from the 60s or 70s.  So logically, it's equivalent to:
`while (curr != 0)` which is the same as `while (curr)`.

Answer (score 2):

**1. head = NULL → why is head being set to NULL?** 
It's good practice to initialize your variables. On some systems declared variables have whatever happened to be in memory when the address space is grabbed.

**2. curr->next = head → I never really understood this as well. Maybe I have my definition of "head" wrong but in a regular linked list, is it the starting node or the last node on the list? I've always assumed it was the starting node but in this line it looks like it's the last node.**
Yes, the head is the starting node.

**3. head = curr → Why are we setting it equal to curr?**
This loop here adds new nodes as the head. Like a stack. Other ways of doing it add new nodes on the tail. Both ways are still "linked lists".

**4. curr = head → and then setting curr = head after the loop is done.**
`curr` is acting like an index, a working variable so you don't distrupt the data structure. He's resetting it after he's done. "Rewinding the tape" if you will.

**5. while(curr) → Just to make sure, this is traversing through the list and it is equivalent to while(curr != NULL) right?**
Yes, that's one of those implied things you find in C. Anything all by itself in a while loop is implicitly `while(whatnot != 0)` and null == 0.

Comment: Ok this is where I was getting confused.. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

In the singly linked list section.. the box with the 'x' in it is the head or the tail?

Comment: @juice: The box with the 'X' inside is the NULL-address. The last element points to it to show 'Hey, I'm the last one, there's no one behind me'. A loop through this list will see this NULL pointer in the last item and then quit the loop.

Comment: Yeah, in that example #12 is the value at the head, and #37 is the value at the tail.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can find the answer to the question why head is always NULL in [Linked List Head Is Always Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556595/linked-list-head-is-always-null)  and [Simple C++ Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095954/simple-c-linked-list). A tutorial for beginner you can find to [singly linked list in c](http://codingfreak.blogspot.com/2010/04/singly-linked-list-in-c.html). The statement head=curr asociated the value of the pointer head what was NULL to the value of the current pointer that receiving a nonzero value by allocating memory. while(curr) is a loop that runs as long curr differ from NULL, NULL as a macro associated zero value for pointing address.

Answer (score 2):

We're starting with nothing. That's what

```
head = NULL;
```

tells us. We have no list yet, so we cannot access it.

Now we're looping from 1 to 10. We build a list from back to front. HEAD is NULL, so the "last" (the first created) points at NULL:

```
curr->next  = head; // head is NULL in the first loop
```

HEAD is now set to this new element:

```
head = curr;
```

The second run through this loop, head stores the pointer to the last created item. The newly created one will then point to it. We set this new item in front of the last item.

Setting

```
head = curr;
```

needs to be done, to ensure, that head contains the right pointer in the next looping. It's called head, because it always stores the beginning of the list that has been created till then.

//4 isn't really necessary.

The last operation before was:

```
head = curr;
```

So

```
curr = head;
```

is senseless.

And the 5th one iterates through the list. "curr" points at the first item (with a non-NULL address) and is set to curr->next in each loop. Once curr is NULL (at the last item), the statement is no longer true.

Answer (score 0):

In the 4th problem,I don't think `curr=head` is necessary.Because when the loop is over,curr and head had pointer the same node(node of i=10).
But it is good habit.