# explanation for this symbol in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

guys what's the meaning of -> in linked list?? explain with example please
I've searched online and none of the site tells what's this thing and just go straight to coding

example

```
start=start->next; // (a)
start->prev = NULL; // (b)
```

is the meaning of

(a) moving start to next node and then assign the next node to start??

(b) idk what it means ,i need explanation thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arrow operator (->) usage in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c)

Comment: Did you see :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441745/explanation-of-code-linked-list-c/15442045#15442045  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, no coding just plain small explanation :-

`->` is structure dereference operator

After execution of above statements

a) start pointer will points to the direct next node of itself.

b) start's previous pointer will be assigned to NULL (indicating end of list)

A *Doubly linked list*, as in your question, is represented as:

[image]

**Start Pointer** is `start` i.e. start/head of node.

**Null** is `NULL` indicates end of list in both the direction.

***next pointer*** signifies `next`

***prev pointer*** signifies `prev`

Comment: how do we know when to put the equal sign??

;et

Comment: let's say start=start->next ,when do we write it as start->next=start??

Comment: @user2421843 I'd suggest, first you go through a pictorial representation of linked list, and then you can answer your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

The `->` symbol is an operator to select an element from a data structure pointed to by a pointer. So suppose you have a pointer defined as `mystruct *p` and it points to a `mystruct` instantiation. Suppose also that `mystruct` declares a variable `i` of, say, type `int`. Then the following notations are equivalent:

```
(*p).i = 2;
```

or

```
p->i = 2;
```

Answer (score -2):

That means delete the start node from a double-side list.

And `->` is an operator .

Comment: can you explain how to use them??

Comment: This does *not* "delete" anything. It sets a pointer to NULL, that's all.

Comment: jongware, can you explain how to use the operator??

Comment: If you do not understand the answers already given: no I can't.

Comment: @Jongware The first node data lost ,if there is no pointer point it ,same as delete.

Comment: You loose the capability to address it from within the program, but the memory will still be marked "in use". Not the same.

Comment: @Jongware we don't konw the memory is in heap or stack.if it is not come from heap , it will be free auto ,right? And yeah, I didn't articulate .Sorry for that.